# What state do I pay taxes to, if I'm nomadic?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax

Let's say I live in an RV and move camps every week or month, moving between states frequently.  When tax time comes, which state do I pay?

Comment: What income do you have? Where is the RV registered? Are you registered to vote?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep - this is all hypothetical.  Let's say 100k, registered in MN.  Where does registered to vote come in?

Comment: MN will claim you're income unless you can prove you have established residency someplace else.  Where did you earn the income.

Comment: https://onemileatatime.com/making-travel-less-taxing-your-tax-home-away-from-home/ This article says though the rules vary by state, for property income it's obviously where the property is that matters. For services income, in general, it matters where you were when you earned the income. Of course each state and city's rules would come into play based on minimum income to file, etc. For IRS purposes you'd probably be classified as itinerant. Short version is as described with significant income it would be a filing nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

The nomadic RV'er:

Vehicle registration is by state. So consider riding the bus and living in various motels in various states instead.

A driver's license has a state but a passport only has a place-of-birth.

If the income is earned like tele-commuting through an office then the office has a state address.

If the income is sent to a financial account then the account must have a residential address. Here, possibly sue for violation of civil rights.

If the income is sent as money orders to the current address, or earned on the spot, then that is interesting except that various states would each expect to be accounted as a part-year residence.

A phone has an area code but a website and e-mail do not. So there is no counterpoint for websites and e-mails except that a domain owner needs at least a P.O. box and the P.O. box has a state.

Most RV'ers would set up a residence in a state that doesn't have an income tax.

Comment: But with cell phones, the area code does not necessarily reflect where you live, just where you originally bought it.  Or signed up with a service provider, since the SIM card can be transferred to new phones.